# Finding root using finmath library in java

Tags: java, implementation, finance, irr

I am trying to implement the  Internal Rate Of Return of some cashflows.

0 = (c1/(1+r)) + (c2/(1+r)^2) + (c3/(1+r)^3) .... like formula and we will be finding the root r.

At this point I am end up with a java library called finmath.

It has a package named net.finmath.rootfinder including these classes

```
BisectionSearch 
NewtonsMethod   
SecantMethod
```

That is ok so far. But, when I try to make use of with my formula there is no method expecting me to enter c1, c2, c3 values as list. The only methods these classes implements are

```
double  getAccuracy() 
double  getBestPoint() 
double  getNextPoint() 
int     getNumberOfIterations() 
boolean isDone() 
void    setValueAndDerivative(double value, double derivative)
```

My question is how can I make use of this library to solve my equation?
I hope some one have any idea about making use of this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bisection Method, Newton's method, Secant Methods are some methods that are used to find/estimate the root of an equation. (Do some maths to know about those methods). To use those mathematical methods, you should have a algebraic equation.

I think the classes you stated implements those mathematical methods of root finding. You should make your equation by substituting values for c1, c2, c3,... and after that you can use those java methods.
I think you have to implement you java method to find the value of the mathematical expression when a value for r is given. (Mathematical expression, not the equation)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I got the point with the library. Because of the fact that no one knows my equation I should have been the one who should generate it. What library does is just to give you a datastructure to make use of in the period of implementing your own solution. I used the Newton-Raphson method. I had to implement it myself, and I did so. Didn't used the library for this purpose.